# Salesforce Messaging.inboundEmail vs Messaging.InboundEnvelope

Tags: email, salesforce

I'm currently writing email handlers for salesforce and am slightly confused about the utility of the Envelope from address compared to the Email from address, the documentation seems to prefer the Envelope details but goes into little detail as to how they differ.

Answer (score 1):

The envelope from address is more likely to be the genuine from address, the email from address is only part of the content of the email.

Comment: The envelope has all the information from the actual SMTP transaction: the MAIL FROM address and the like. THe email object is all of the SMTP stuff after the data command.